# Parsing log file

Tags: regex, macos, bash, sed, grep

I am trying to parse a text like this from a log file:

> [2016-01-29 11:31:33,809: WARNING/Worker-1283]
>   1030140:::DEAL_OF_DAY:::29:::1:::11 [2016-01-29 11:31:34,103:
>   WARNING/Worker-1197] 1025311:::DEAL_OF_DAY:::29:::1:::11 [2016-01-29
>   11:31:34,291: WARNING/Worker-1197] 1025158:::DEAL_OF_DAY:::29:::1:::11

I want to extract these numbers 1030140, 1025311, 1025158 and so on.

I have tried the following

`cat deals29.txt | egrep -o '[0-9]+'`

But this gives other digits as well

I tried
`cat deals29.txt | egrep -o ' [0-9]+:::'`

but now it gives the colons in the output as well and there is no way to capture the group in the command line version of grep.

Any suggestions? `grep` solution would be preferred but I can go with sed/awk as well if grep cannot do the job.

Comment: ].[0-9]\w+   this will also useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grep -oP` and match reset `\K`:

```
grep -oP '^\[.*?\] \K\d+' file.log
1030140
1025311
1025158
```

If your `grep` doesn't support `-P` (PCRE) then use `awk`:

```
awk -F '\\] |:::' '{print $2}' file.log
1030140
1025311
1025158
```

Answer (score 0):

You can train regex here : https://regex101.com/

I get

```
] [0-9]*
```

and you have to delete the first 2 chars

Comment: I don't want to delete first 2 chars manually. That's the point.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a solution like:

```
(\d{3,})::
# looks for at least 3 digits (or more) followed by two colons
# puts the matched numbers in group 1
```

See a demo for this approach [here](https://regex101.com/r/iD4jX5/1).